# Is there a closed form such that integration agrees with the geodesic metric?

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry

A closed form on a Riemannian manifold, $(M,g)$ is a form such that $d\omega=0$. This means that the integral of a curve with two points as it’s endpoints is independent of the path taken. Is $d(p,q)\equiv |\int_p^q \omega|$ a metric for some $\omega \in \Omega^1 (M)$ with $M$ being simply-connected?

If so, does there exist a closed form such that $d(p,q)$ is equal to the geodesic metric given by $i(p,q)\equiv \inf_{\gamma} \lambda (\gamma)$ where lambda is the function taking a curve and giving its length and gamma is a geodesic with $p$ and $q$ as it’s endpoints.

Are there any resources you could recommend as well?

Comment: Have you tried this on a simple example, like $\mathbb{R}^2\cong\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: For starters, the Kähler  form is a $(1,1)$-form. How do you intend to integrate it over a real curve?

Comment: I fixed the problem.

Comment: No, you did not fix the problem. You have to add more assumptions such as $\alpha$ is a 1-form, $M$ is simply-connected (otherwise, your integral is not well-defined). Now, suppose that $\alpha$ is identically zero, does your integral define a metric?

Comment: **HINT**: $\omega=0$ is integrable. So along any integral submanifold, all points will be distance $0$ from one another. Try this for $M=\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: Even if $\omega$ is never the $0$-form there will always be points with distance zero. This is just because $\mathrm{ker}(\omega)$ is a subbundle of the tangent bundle, and so you can find a curve $c$ with $c^\prime(t) \in \mathrm{ker}(\omega_{c(t)})$.

Comment: @FriederJäckel Well, that makes two of us with that complaint.

Comment: @Frieder Ok, thanks. My train of thought for this was that it was possible to find a form that avoided problems similar to the one you pointed out

Comment: What makes complex geometry so amazing is that in that setting (e.g., a Kähler manifold) there is a global $2$-form $\omega$ so that $\omega^k/k!$ gives the induced volume form on *every* $k$-dimensional *complex* submanifold. But nothing like this over $\Bbb R$.